# Execution default-integration-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:integration-test failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to run Apache Taverna engine source code on eclipse.i am using maven 3.6.0 . I keep having this error every time I try to run mvn install.when i try mvn clean get success build.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Taverna Engine and Platform 3.1.0-incubating  SUCCESS [  3.337 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Reference Manager API ............... SUCCESS [ 31.216 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Observer pattern .................... SUCCESS [ 15.924 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Workflow Model API .................. SUCCESS [01:39 min]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Workflow Model Extension Points ..... SUCCESS [ 27.037 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Workflow Model impl ................. SUCCESS [ 48.149 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Database Configuration API .......... SUCCESS [ 14.536 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Reference Test Helpers .............. SUCCESS [ 17.615 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Reference Manager impl .............. SUCCESS [ 28.480 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Engine Reference Types .............. SUCCESS [ 28.556 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Activity test utils ................. SUCCESS [  4.223 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Activity archetype .................. FAILURE [  5.293 s]
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Capability API ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Capability impl ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Credential Manager API .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Credential Manager impl ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Database Configuration impl ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Dataflow Activity ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Report Service ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Execution Service API ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Hadoop Workflow Execution Service ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Execution Service impl ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Local Execution Service .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Remote Execution Service ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Run Service API ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Run Service impl ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Services API ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna Platform Services impl .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Taverna StringConstant Activity 3.1.0-incubating SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:26 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-21T13:50:00+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project taverna-activity-archetype: Execution default-integration-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:integration-test failed: ${maven.home} is not specified as a directory: 'C:\Users\Ahlem\eclipse-workspace\apache-taverna\apache-taverna\EMBEDDED'. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :taverna-activity-archetyp
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862153/build-sling-failure-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-arche

Comment: try using external maven instead using m2eclipse uses by default.

Answer (score 1):

This seems related with a [known Eclipse issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341120).

As a workaround you can use an external mvn instead of the embedded one which Eclipse uses by default.

Workaround steps:

1. Unzip a maven distribution on your machine.
2. In Eclipse navigate to Window -> preference -> Maven -> Installations, and add the Maven installation you just unzipped.
3. A new launch configuration will use the new one. If you try an existing launch configuration you need to update the "Maven Runtime" used at the bottom of the main tab of Launch Configuration dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

```
1. Go to Preferences->Maven-Installation->  Click the "Add " button to add external maven you had downloaded ,Then click the "Ok" or "Apply' button to save. 
2. For you current maven project, you need to right click the project or pom.xml file ,choose "Run As"->"Run Configurations", find current maven run setting, at the bottom there's a "maven Runtime" setting , for the dropdown list to select the previous added maven ,Then click the "Apply" button to make it affect .
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to skip tests by using this command in console:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

In Eclipse you can do it by adding a new maven build configuration, you could check this link [How to skip maven unit test in Eclipse](http://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test-in-eclipse/) if you don't know how to do it